# XMLCAST in oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with an xml column and trying to do sum of values in an xml tag.

Table created:
CREATE TABLE XML_TABLE6
(
XML_COL  VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE)
);

```
Insert into XML_TABLE6
   (XML_COL)
 Values
   ('<a><b>1</b><b>2</b></a>');
COMMIT;
```

I am using the below select statement to return the expression in datatype "double". But i am getting the error "ORA-00905: missing keyword".

SQL query:

select XMLCast(XMLQuery('sum(a/b)' RETURNING CONTENT)
as double) from xml_table6;

Expected output: 3.0

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues in the query:

- You didn't specify the column you want to take as input (`XML_passing_clause`)
- You need to explicitly cast the column to the XMLType instance to process it with XML functions.
- Oracle doesn't have `double` data type. See [numeric data types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-9401BC04-81C4-4CD5-99E7-C5E25C83F608) in the documentation. [`XMLCAST`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLCAST.html#GUID-06563B93-1247-4F0C-B6BE-42DB3B1DB069) function:

> The datatype argument **can be of data type** NUMBER, VARCHAR2, CHAR, CLOB, BLOB, REF XMLTYPE, and any of the datetime data types.

After you've fixed this issues, it works fine:

```
with XML_TABLE6(XML_COL) as (
  select '<a><b>1</b><b>2</b></a>'
  from dual
)
select xmlcast(
    XMLQuery('sum(a/b)' passing xmltype(XML_COL) RETURNING CONTENT)
    as binary_double
  ) as res
from XML_TABLE6

|RES|
|:--|
|3.0E+000|
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KZQlM1zx)

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, [the ANSI data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0BC16006-32F1-42B1-B45E-F27A494963FF) is `double precision`, not just `double`.

You also need to pass in the actual column value, and as that's a string, convert it to XMLType:

```
select
  XMLCast(
    XMLQuery('sum(a/b)' PASSING XMLType(xml_col) RETURNING CONTENT)
    as double precision)
from xml_table6;
```

Or use a normal [`number`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-75209AF6-476D-4C44-A5DC-5FA70D701B78) data type:

```
select 
  XMLCast(
    XMLQuery('sum(a/b)' PASSING XMLType(xml_col) RETURNING CONTENT)
    as number
   )
from xml_table6;
```

Or [`binary_double`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-12FE5221-9B49-4110-8D16-BF51BCED5562):

```
select 
  XMLCast(
    XMLQuery('sum(a/b)' PASSING XMLType(xml_col) RETURNING CONTENT)
    as binary_double
   )
from xml_table6;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nSsPT78k)